# <M>:= the intersection of subspace U such that U is a subspace of L containing M

Tags: projective-geometry

L is a linear space and set M is the set of points of L. The definition I put above is "the smallest subspace of L generated by M". The thing I don't understand in this definition is why do we need the brackets around M; how come we can't just say M the set of points which is the smallest subspace? Also U is not equal to the intersection of U?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition $$
  \langle M \rangle := \bigcap \left\{U \,:\, U \text{ subspace of $L$, $M \subset U$} \right\}
$$
doesn't define $M$, it defines the behaviour of the operator $\langle\cdot\rangle$. This operator maps every *subset* $M$ of $L$ to the smallest *subspace* of $L$ which contains $M$. That subspace is often called, as you state, the subspace *generated* by $M$.

It is certainly *not* true that $M = \langle M \rangle$. You always have that $\langle M \rangle \supset M$ (because $\langle M\rangle$ is the intersection of sets which *all* contain $M$), and $\langle M \rangle$ is *always* a subspace (because it's the intersection of subspaces). Thus, $M = \langle M \rangle$ holds exactly if $M$ is a subspace.

Comment: Great. Big help!